# Tortoisesvn seems stuck in non-recursive mode

Tags: windows-10, tortoise-svn

Just set up a new machine, running windows 10, and installed TortoiseSVN 1.9.4, Build 27285 - 64 Bit

Did plenty of reboots, needed the first one for the icons to appear. However it seems to be stuck in non-recursive mode. The icons are all there, working correctly, but when I click on a parent folder, it says there's nothing to commit. If I drill down to the child-most folder, and try to commit, it seems to figure out what files to commit. It's just a pain in the butt to have to drill down to every folder just to get the committing working, seems broken to me, or is there some setting for this?

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem. One of the subdirectories, had an old svn repo in it. Had to do a clean-up, but also had to select break locks. Seems to have fixed the problem.